# What does Dense do?

Tags: keras, convolution, keras-layer

What is the meaning of the two `Dense` in this code?

```
self.model.add(Flatten())
self.model.add(Dense(512))
self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Dense(10))
self.model.add(Activation('softmax'))
self.model.summary()
```

Answer (score 12):

`Dense` is the only actual network layer in that model.

A `Dense` layer feeds all outputs from the previous layer to all its neurons, each neuron providing one output to the next layer.

It's the most basic layer in neural networks.

A `Dense(10)` has ten neurons. A `Dense(512)` has 512 neurons.

Answer (score 6):

Furthermore, a [dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense) layers applies the a non-linear transform:

> f(W.X + b)

As to the effect, well in the case that W and X are a 2D tensor  W.X + b is a vector and f is a element wise non-linearity like tanh, so the result is just a vector of size in the numbers of neurons

From the keras docs:

> Dense implements the operation: output = activation(dot(input, kernel)
>
> - bias) where activation is the element-wise activation function passed as the activation argument, kernel is a weights matrix created
>   by the layer, and bias is a bias vector created by the layer (only
>   applicable if use_bias is True).

Comment: In this context what is tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures. Does DenseFeatures too apply non linearity?